# Is there a standalone color picker utility that uses this style of a colour picking dialog?

Tags: windows, color, utility

I have come across a few programs that use the dialog from the below screenshot, its a single dialog with 5 tabs, first 3 tabs contain a different colour wheel, last 2 tabs consist of colour swatches. For example, Clip Studio Paint uses this dialog.

I am looking to use this utility as a unified/replacement colour picker utility  for various graphic design software's, primarily as a means of achieving:

- Consistent interface for picking a colour
- Shared colour history between software's
- Consistent hotkeys/navigation

I will handle getting and setting active colour in the graphic design applications with AutoHotkey.

I am having trouble actually finding a utility that uses this kind of colour picking dialog.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]